# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to have a function run upon re-sizing the window. I got this code from somewhere and am trying to implement it. The function itself is working nicely on page load. But everytime it calls the $(window).resize I get the above error in the console.

here's the code:

```
var bg = $(".mw_fsbg");
$(window).resize("resizeBackground");
function resizeBackground() {

    /* set background of fullscreen fixed div to 100% and welcome div also */
    bg.height($(window).height());
}

resizeBackground();
```

Comment: You don't need (or really want) to quote the name of the function to pass it as an argument. Its name will become a local variable you can use. `$(window).resize(resizeBackground);`

Comment: $(window).resize(function (){ /* stuff here */});

Comment: out of curiosity if your mw_fsbg height is the complete height of your window, why dont you use height:100% attribute?( .mw_fsbg{height:100%;}

Comment: @Sai Because on mobile devices the viewport changes height a little bit upon scrolling down, because of the browser's address bar. I want it to change upon load and upon window resize only so that it doesn't "snap in place" when scrolling.

If you like to, you can check out the live effect on a mobile device here: mwd.mostwanted-designs.nl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quote from the parameter:

```
$(window).resize(resizeBackground);
```

Comment: Can't believe I haven't thought of trying that. Thanks so much.